# signalR chat-check if message was sent successfully

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I made a chat using signalR hub and it works fine. 
Now what I want to do is that the server should send a notification to the client if their message was sent successfully.How can I do this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want a notifications when messages reach the server? Or when messages reach their destination client? If it's the latter, the receiving clients will need to manually ACK messages.

Comment: how I make the receiving client manually acknowledge it?
I am using clients.client(id )in my hub class to send the message to a particular client.What I want is when the message is received successfully by the other client it displays 'successful' on the the sender client's screen.

Answer (score 5):

To be sure that the message reached the client successfully, in the client method that receives the message, you should call a server method to acknowledge it.

For example, on the server, you have

```
Clients.All.hello();
```

On the client, you should do something like this:

```
myHubConnection.client.hello = function () {
     //do your stuff
     myHubConnection.server.notifyTheServer(messageId);
};
```